# Find stationary point functions

Tags: calculus, functions

I was looking back at my notes on functions : [image]

I decided to attempt my own question, however I can only go so far until I get lost.

Suppose $f(x)=ln(x^2 - 6x + 2)$  Then

$$f'(x) = {2x - 6 \over x^2 -6x + 2}.$$

We see that $f'$ changes sign at $x = 3$ and at the roots of $x^2 - 6x + 2$.

My problem is I don't understand the table at the end if someone could explain to me, I'm pretty poor at maths so if you can as basic an explanation  as possible that'd be fantastic.

Thanks guys

Comment: The table indicates the sign $f'(x)$ assumes as $x$ varies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you call a stationary point is what I call a critical point -- i.e. one where f'(x) = 0 (or possibly a boundary point if f is defined on [a,b]).  Let's call it x = c.

Whether c is a max, a min or neither can be determined in a number of ways.

1. If f''(c) exists and it is > 0 at c you have a min; < 0 at c you have a max.  If f''(c) = 0 you cannot draw any conclusion. Handy if it works.
2. If f''(x) does not exist, you can look at f'(x) in the neighborhood of the critical point.

For example, if f'(x) is positive when x < c and negative when x > c you have a max; and a min if vice-versa. If f'(x) is positive at all points in a neighborhood of c then you have neither a max nor a min.  Same if f' is negative throughout a neighborhood of c.

Now can you explain why these things should be so?  If you can, you don't really need the chart.  And if you can't, it would be good to review what f'(x) really means.